# AngularJS ui-grid and custom directive updation

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid for creating sortable tables along with pagination. When I go for pagination, a service call is made in the background which returns a new set of data which is then updated in the table.
I have written a directive for cell template, the directive checks the data object for a keyName "context" and based on the value of the "context" it sets a particular image for the cell template.
The problem is that this directive works fine for the first set of records, but when I fetch the next set of records using paginate, the table shows the new records but the directive does not updates the images for the cell template.
I have found a solution by adding a watch inside the directive and now it works as intended.
My question is there some other way to deal with above issue?

My column definition, cell template has my custom directive "account-type-icon"

```
    {
      name:'Name',
      field: 'entityName' ,
      sort : gridDecorator.getInitialSortState(vm.metadata.sorters, 'entityName'),
      sortDirectionCycle :   ['asc', 'desc'],
      headerCellClass : 'headercell',
      cellClass : 'gridcell',
      minWidth : 300,
      enableSorting : gridDecorator.isTheColumnSortable('entityName'),
      cellTemplate : '<td><a ui-sref=""><**account-type-icon** context="row.entity.contextType"></account-type-icon> {{row.entity.entityName}}</a></td>'
    },
```

The "account-type-icon" is my directive,

```
return {
  restrict: 'EA',
  replace: true,
  template: '<i></i>',
  scope: {
    context: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, iElement) {
    //console.log(scope);
    var context = scope.context;
    if (context !== undefined && typeof context === 'number') {
      var iconClass = mapContext(context);
      if (iconClass) { iElement.addClass(iconClass); }
    }

    function mapContext (context) {
      switch(context) {
        case 1:
          // accounts
          return 'glyphicons glyphicons-book';
        case 2:
          // clients
          return 'glyphicons glyphicons-user';
        case 3:
          // groups
          return 'glyphicons glyphicons-address-book';
        case 4:
          // households
          return 'glyphicons glyphicons-home';
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }
   //this watch solves my problem of icon updation
    scope.$watch('context',function(newContextValue){
      if (newContextValue !== undefined && typeof newContextValue === 'number') {
        var iconClass = mapContext(newContextValue);
        if (iconClass) {
          iElement.removeClass('glyphicons-book glyphicons-user glyphicons-address-book glyphicons-home');
          iElement.addClass(iconClass);
        }
      }
    });
  },
  controller: ['$scope',function ($scope){
      //console.log($scope);
  }]
};
```

Is there any other elegant way of letting the directive know that it needs to update the images for cells?